# Why is there a %26 (Python)?

Tags: python, encryption, key, caesar-cipher

I am trying to decipher a text from user without knowing the key in caesar cipher.

I probably understand most of it but I don't get it why they use the mod 26 on line 8

```
alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
    'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
print('write the message you want to decode?')
inputString = input()
inputString = inputString.lower()

transAlphabet = {}

def createDict(shift):
    for i in range(0,26):
        letter = alphabet[i]

        transAlphabet[letter]=alphabet[(i+shift)%26]


def encodeMessage(message):
    cypherText = ''
    for letter in message:
        if letter in transAlphabet:

            cypherText = cypherText + transAlphabet[letter]
        else:
            cypherText = cypherText + letter
    print(cypherText)

for i in range(0,26):
    createDict(i)
    encodeMessage(inputString)
```

Please would be really helpful if someone helps me out thank you!

Comment: Read the title I've just edited : the title should reflect the problem without openning the post, your title was empty of information ;)

Comment: Character values can only be in the range 0:25. When you add the shift, some will be outside of that range so %26 essentially loops them around back in range

Comment: Think about it: what is the possible range of values `i + shift` could have? Are those values all valid indices for the list? What happens to the values when `% 26` is applied to them?

Comment: For every possible shift value `t` (0-25) it's creating a dictionary `shiftedalph` where each letter a-z becomes a key and the shifted letter is the value (e,g, `'a': 'b'` when t=1), then using that dictionary to create a new message using the dictionary, where each letter in turn is looked up in the dictionary and an encrypted string is output.

Comment: OH that makes so much sense!!! thank you so much! But what happens in the next bit of program? Really appreciate it :)! like ``If letter in message `` I don't get that bit

Comment: Oh dw David, so basically every letter is looked up in the dictionary then, in the 26 outputs in recieve, each time the letter is chnaged to the one in dictionary. Did i get it right?

Comment: You might want to start using underscores. ```shifted_characters_in_the_inputted_text``` is so much easier on the eyes compared to ```shiftedcharactersintheinputtedtext```

Comment: You seem to have deleted all of your code from the question... `if letter in shiftedalpha` checks that the character from the message is actually a letter by checking if it's in the shiftedalph dictionary. If not (e.g. a space) it doesn't try looking it up.

Comment: Nah I just organised my code so that it might be helpful of anyone else looks through.

Comment: Ok so lets say the character from message is a letter what does it do then? Also how can I like upvote you man, you're really great!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo `%26` is to make the alphabet circular, when you're at `z` come back at `a`

Example for `alph[(i + shift) % 26]` with `i=20` and `shift=10`

- without modulo you'll like to reach index `30` in the array and it doesn't not exist
- with modulo you'll reach index `30%26 = 4` in the array, letter `e`

---

But also your algo is a bt strange, I would have done the shifting on the fly for each car, but your solution may be more efficient for long text as you don't need to compute the shift everytime.

Not computing the shifted alphabet before would look like this

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
alphabet = ascii_lowercase

def encode_message(message, shift):
    cypher_text = ''
    for letter in message:
        letter_idx = alphabet.index(letter)
        cypher_text = cypher_text + alphabet[(letter_idx + shift) % 26]
    return cypher_text

def decode_message(message, shift):
    cypher_text = ''
    for letter in message:
        letter_idx = alphabet.index(letter)
        cypher_text = cypher_text + alphabet[(26 + letter_idx - shift) % 26]
    return cypher_text
```